how to click cq-toggle element dynamically using javascript
how to click cq-toggle element dynamically using javascript?
When i click manually on cq-toggle menu item it actually adds active class to the element cq-toggle and add one div content in document HTML. I want to click cq-toggle dynamically using javascript.
<div class="ciq-menu-section">
    <div class="ciq-dropdowns">
        <cq-toggle class="ciq-DT tableview-ui" cq-member="tableView">
              <span></span>
              <cq-tooltip>
                 <translate original="Table View">Table View</translate>
              </cq-tooltip>
        </cq-toggle>

I have tried
 const tableViewToggle = frameDocument.querySelector(".tableview-ui")
 tableViewToggle.click();

also
tableViewToggle.classList.toggle('active');

but it is not working.

not sure what you're trying to do

i want to click cq-toggle using javascript code.

document.querySelector(".tableview-ui").addEventListener('click', event => { event.target.classList.toggle('active') }) - try this
